# show function not working with imagemap

Tags: javascript, jquery, show, imagemap, area

I have an imagemap and want to use the show function to fade in some, rectangle div. But it's not responding.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".levert").click(function () {
$("#popUpDiv").show("slow");
});

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="logo" src="./logo2.png" alt="Phlox" usemap="#links"><p class="logotext">Phlox</p></img>

<map name="links">
<area shape="circle" coords="294,46,46" href="#" class="levert"></area>
</map>

</div>
<div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#popUpDiv {
      position:absolute;
      background-color:#3F6;
      width:400px;
      height:400px;
      border:5px solid #000;
      z-index: 9002;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your code in a document ready call:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".levert").click(function() {
        $("#popUpDiv").show("slow");
    });
});
</script>​
```

Comment: yeah read about this why is this necessary ? don't know the meaning of this function EDIT: i think i know the meaning first the jquery.js has to be loaded before you can script something with it.

Comment: This assures that the code will load as soon as the DOM is loaded and before the page contents are loaded. otherwise without it it will try to execute before the page (and the contents that you want the code to work on) are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in Fx17 and Chrome 22 on Mac if I do it after the page loads

```
$(function() { .... });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/ssNXV/)